# MongoDB nested grouping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB data model:

```js
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53725814740fd6d2ee0ca2bb"),
"date" : "2014-01-01",
"establishmentId" : 1,
"products" : [
    {
        "productId" : 1,
        "price" : 7.03,
        "someOtherInfo" : 325,
        "somethingElse" : 6878
    },
    {
        "productId" : 2,
        "price" : 4.6,
        "someOtherInfo" : 243,
        "somethingElse" : 1757
    },
    {
        "productId" : 3,
        "price" : 2.14,
        "someOtherInfo" : 610,
        "somethingElse" : 5435
    },
    {
        "productId" : 4,
        "price" : 1.45,
        "someOtherInfo" : 627,
        "somethingElse" : 5762
    },
    {
        "productId" : 5,
        "price" : 3.9,
        "someOtherInfo" : 989,
        "somethingElse" : 3752
    }
}
```

What is the fastest way to get the average price across all establishments? Is there a better data model to achieve this?

Comment: I assume you mean avg price per product? (as opposed to across all products?)  Either way, the answer is using aggregation framework with $unwind on products array, and $group calculating average using $avg operator.

Answer (score 0):

An [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) operation should handle this well. I'd suggest looking into the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation.

Something along these lines should work (just as an example):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$match: {<query parameters>}},
  {$unwind: "$products"},
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: "<blank or field(s) to group by before averaging>",
      $avg: "$price"
    }
  }
);
```

An aggregation built in this style should produce a JSON object that has the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the gross syntax errors in anything else provided the more direct answer is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "avgprice": { "$avg": "$products.price" }
    }}
])
```

The usage of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) here is to first [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array, which is a way to "de-normalize" the content in the array into separate documents.

Then in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage you pass in a value of `null` to the `_id` which means "group everything" and pass your `$products.price` ( note the dot notation ) in to the [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operator to return the total average value across all of the sub-document entries in all of your documents in the collection.

See the [full operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{date:{$gte:"2014-01-01",$lte:"2014-01-31"},establishmentId:{$in:[1,2,3,4,5,6]}}
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {date:"$date",product:"$products.productId"},
        "avgprice": { "$avg": "$products.price" }
    }}
])
```

And something I found out also was that it is much better to first use match and then unwind so there are fewer items to unwind. This results in a faster overall process.